# mysql - php - remove first part of url upon INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, url, file-upload

Im doing an image gallery CMS using Mysql database and PHP. Im a newbie.

Im having a path problem.

here is my file structure:
this php doc  -  `root/php/upload_portrait.php`.
My images are stored here  -   `root/images/portrait_gallery/`

So I added the `../` to save the images in `root/images/portrait_gallery/`
that works fine.

but in the db the url is stored with the ../ and that path is incorrect since they are being called from the root index file. So no images show up.

HOW can I remove the `../` upon `INSERT INTO` in the database??

I have tried with replace and update but cant figure out how.

Here Is my code

```
$portrait_url= $_FILES['upload'];

// 2. connect to database: 
include 'connect.php';

// 4. handle moving image from temp location to images folder (using the function billedupload)
$billedurl = billedupload($portrait_url);       
if($billedurl == false){        
    die("Something is wrong");
}

// 5. Insert imageupload in database:
$query = "INSERT INTO portrait (portrait_id, portrait_url) VALUES ('$portrait_id', '$billedurl')";
$result = mysqli_query($dblink, $query) or die( "Forespørgsel 2 kunne ikke udføres: " . mysqli_error($dblink) );

// 6. close connection
mysqli_close($dblink);

function billedupload($filearray){      
    if($filearray['type']=='image/jpeg' or $filearray['type']=='image/png'){
        $tmp_navn = $filearray['tmp_name'];             
        $filnavn = $filearray['name'];          
        $url = '../images/portrait_gallery/' . time() . $filnavn;           
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_navn, $url);            
    return $url;    
    } 
    else{           
        return false;       
    }   
}
```

Comment: instead of returning the whole path($url), just return the file name i.e. Return $fileavn. Thats what you need to store in db and as the developer you have the idea where you have stored images and can call upon necessity.

Comment: but to avoid duplication you should create your own naming pattern for storing images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need to to remove '/..' -- then,

`str_replace` is a function in PHP that allows you to remove/change parts of strings on the fly, so, in your code,

replace

`$billedurl = billedupload($portrait_url);`

with

`$billedurl = str_replace('/..','',billedupload($portrait_url));`

Comment: str_replace works like a charm. Thank you all for you time :-)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have 2 choices.

1. Alter the $url line of billed upload() and remove the ../ there, since you know you won't need it when you go to read it.
2. Alter your function that reads from the database and remove the ../ there.

str_replace() is probably the function you need, as mentioned by previous poster.